# Program the official rom of samsung phone

Tags: rooting, samsung, custom-roms, rom

Is there a way to program the official rom of a samsung phone?

for example to add a feature on the rom that doesn't exist or just the only way is to create your own custom rom?

My phone is Samsung Galaxy Note 5 Marshmallow 6.0.1. A feature that I want to add is the ability to mark as read messages from notifications without open them. (I don't want to create an app for this that's why am asking how to program the official rom)

Comment: Your question is not clear. *What* is that you want to add as a  * feature*? It may be possible by proper means. What is your device? Please edit your question to make it specific with device and OS details.

Comment: Those firmwares are signed and only Samsung has the key, so you can't modify it or the MD5 hash will fail! And you cannot add "features" if the hardware doesn't meet the requirements.

Comment: If you're rooted and skillful enough, you can do framework-res and SystemUI mods that somewhat alter the UI and functions. For example, many older Samsung phones can have newer model's features ported over this way. But you do need to be clear as @beeshyams said.

Comment: @AndyYan Thanks man you completely answer my question

Comment: Samsung developed what I requested here.

Probably they saw it from here :p